# Is it possible to add member to office 365 group having read access to its SharePoint site

Tags: office365, sharepoint-online

Need to add users to Office 365 group but at the same time they should have read access.

When try to add user to office 365, user get edit access to sharepoint site associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

On the SharePoint site, you can set the permissions that the different SharePoint groups have. Out of the box, there will be three groups:

- Site Owners have full control
- Site Members have edit permissions
- Site Visitors have read permissions

The fastest way to get members read only access is to change the permissions for that group.

Go to Site Settings > Site Permissions, or `https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName/_layouts/15/user.aspx`

Tick the box for the Members group and click the ribbon command **Edit user permissions**. In the next page, untick "Read" and tick "Edit".

[image]

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. This would change the permission for all the members who having the Edit access. Can't we change permission of specific office 365 group member in Sharepoint.

Comment: Yes. You never said you wanted to change access for only specific people. In that case, remove the specific people from the SharePoint Members group and add them to the SharePoint Visitors group instead.